# Why is my framer motion h1 component offset in my React project?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, framer-motion

So i have a problem when i use framer motion on my h1

```
import { motion } from "framer-motion";
function FirstPage() {
  return (
    <motion.h1
      initial={{ opacity: 0, scale: 0.5, y: -100, x: -100 }}
      animate={{ opacity: 1, scale: 1 }}
      transition={{
        duration: 0.8,
        delay: 0.5,
        ease: [0, 0.71, 0.2, 1.01],
      }}
    >
      Tehauto
    </motion.h1>
  );
}
```

In css i center this h1 and in the animation i do not change the x coordinate
but for some reason it is offset to the right
Idk if it matters but i have bootstrap installed also

[with framer motion (picture link)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuczv.png)

[when i use regular h1 (picture link)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ittdo.png)

I tried to delete the entire heading and then save and then rewrite it again but it didnt work

Comment: I think you should try to inspect on h1 heading on console in devtools.

Comment: i did and i got this
<h1 style="opacity: 1; transform: translateX(-100px) translateY(-100px) scale(1) translateZ(0px);">Tehauto</h1>

Comment: can you share a minimal example(code sandbox) for this so, I could do some changes to it?

Comment: i uploaded the code here https://stackblitz.com/edit/tehautov3

Comment: Hi, when I click on the given link it gives me the error related to vite. So, can you recheck and update it so, I could check on the **expected issue**.

Comment: i think i fixed it but now i have an issue i didnt have before: when you resize the webview at one point the text dissapears and there is only a white stripe

Comment: and the offset problem is gone i dont understand why. When i run it locally the h1 is still offset

Comment: Hi, I added my ans please try to see if it helps you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to solve your all issues!!

> Idk if it matters but I have bootstrap installed also

**It doesn't matter whether you have installed bootstrap**(styling can also be overridden well).

The main thing is that you need to create `div` & wrap it, also use inline styling in both `h1` & `div`.
like this you can do it:

```
//...
     <div
        style={{
          height: '0px',
          width: '100px',
          top: '200px',
          color: 'white',
          left: '40%',
          position: 'relative',
        }}
      >
        <motion.h1
          initial={{
            left: -30,
            position: 'relative',
            opacity: 0,
            scale: 0.5,
            y: -100,
          }}
          style={{
            fontSize: '80px',
            visibility: 'visible',
          }}
          animate={{ opacity: 1, scale: 1 }}
          transition={{
            duration: 0.8,
            delay: 0.5,
            ease: [0, 0.71, 0.2, 1.01],
          }}
        >
          Tehauto
        </motion.h1>
      </div>
//...
```

Here is the update [example link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/tehautov3-9sqe9p?file=src%2Ffirst-page.tsx).

You can mess around with it.

I hope this helps!